# ACTION_USER_PRESENT in ICS causes Force Close

Tags: java, android, eclipse, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to receive the event ACTION_USER_PRESENT when the screen is unlocked. I have a registered broadcast receiver which should give a log message when the screen is turned on, then unlocked. It shows the message for the screen on, but will crash the app during screen unlock (user present).

Any ideas? I have searched about this many times with no luck. I am on ICS 4.0+ by the way and tested on multiple devices.

**Here is my broadcast**

```
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("BRODCASTRECEIVER", "MAIN");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            // do whatever you need to do here
            Log.d("BRODCASTRECEIVER", "SCREEN OFF");
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            // and do whatever you need to do here
            Log.d("BRODCASTRECEIVER", "SCREEN ON");
        }
        else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)) {
            Log.d("BRODCASTRECEIVER", "UNLOCK");
        }
        }
    };
```

**Here is how i register it**

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    registerReceiver(Receiver, intentFilter);
```

**Here is the Manifest**

```
    <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

**Logcat**

```
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver jp.dip.sugarhouse.lockscreenoverlay.MyBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jp.dip.sugarhouse.lockscreenoverlay.MyBroadcastReceiver
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2100)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1197)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jp.dip.sugarhouse.lockscreenoverlay.MyBroadcastReceiver
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2095)
12-09 12:39:45.582: E/AndroidRuntime(12710):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash. If you do not understand the stack trace, add it to your question via the "edit" link.

Comment: Run your program again and post what the logcat says after it crashes. Make sure it's not the deprecated logcat.